# Apache and Japanase website re-write module

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use to work on a multilingual website, within the next few months, we added Korean and we are now adding Japanese. Apart the fact that it generate a huge list of 404 errors on the logs files, I am having another issue with the urls. The Apache server response with a Bad request when I insert this url:

学校-詳細な評価-11

```
#[.htaccess]
RewriteRule ^学校-詳細な評価-(.+)$ /statistics.php?n=$1 [L]
```

I tried also using the [B] flag, but nothing changes.

I tried as well to remove character and I found that it only works if I do in this way:

```
#[.htaccess]
RewriteRule ^学-(.+)$ /statistics.php?n=$1 [L]
```

But of course I cannot avoid the issue in this way :D

I notice that Apache will convert the url to: 
%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1-%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%AA%E8%A9%95%E4%BE%A1-11

Then I tried it as well:

```
#[.htaccess]
RewriteRule ^%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1-%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%AA%E8%A9%95%E4%BE%A1-(.+)$ /statistics.php?n=$1 [L]
```

But I'm still having the issue :(

Does anyone know how to fix it or why this is happening? I did a research but all forums and website only suggest to use the flag B at the end of the url.

Any help is welcome! Thank you :)

Comment: I always thought that URLs could only use western characters, as they would be extremely difficult to type if they contained eastern characters, characters with accents, Cyrillic characters etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try in Hex:

```
RewriteRule ^\xE5\xAD\xA6\xE6\xA0\xA1-\xE8\xA9\xB3\xE7\xB4\xB0\xE3\x81\xAA\xE8\xA9\x95\xE4\‌​xBE\xA1-(.+)$ /statistics.php?n=$1 [L]
```

For example with having this rule:

`RewriteRule ^\xE5\xAD\xA6-(.+)$ /statistics.php [L]`

this url `http://domain.com/学-t` will redirect to `http://domain.com/statistics.php`

For testing you can use online htaccess tester: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and **remember** to change the page encoding to ***UTF-8*** before testing.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but still not working. thank, any other suggestion? :(

Comment: @BrunoQuintanaFleitas it works as I tested. what's the problem at ur case?

Comment: I got bad request error on my Apache(it is a share hosting). I didn't test in that website.